# Sorting a DataFrame such that NA values on the first sort column would be at the end regardless of the secondary sort columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `DataFrame.sort` and aiming for the default behavior of pushing all the NA values to the end.

The problem is that as you add secondary sort columns, NA values on the first sort column don't behave like non-NA values. Apparently if you have NA in the first column, it will be overridden by the secondary columns if they aren't NA.

For example:

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame([[1, 1], [None, 0]])

In [2]: df.sort([0])
Out[2]: 
    0  1
0   1  1
1 NaN  0

In [3]: df.sort([0, 1])
Out[3]: 
    0  1
1 NaN  0
0   1  1
```

The last sort demonstrates the undesirable behavior: the value on the first sort column (0) is NaN, so record 1 should be at the end. It's not, because apparently the second column (1) takes precedence.

Is there any way to sort `df` such that the secondary sort column would only be used to resolve equality among the first sort column, while still keeping all NAs at the end, regardless of secondary column value?

Comment: Which version of pandas do you have? I can't replicate the second example with 0.15.2

Comment: Yes this works as desired on pandas 0.16.0 too

Comment: @chrisaycock This is 0.13.1

Comment: upgrade is my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was a bug that was fixed. I was using Pandas 0.13.1. Upgrading to 0.16.1 produced the desired behavior:

```
In [4]: df.sort([0, 1])
Out[4]: 
    0  1
0   1  1
1 NaN  0
```